# node-static add headers via cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-static

I have a question about cli use of the [`node-static`](https://npmjs.com/package/node-static) library.

I can go to a folder and just run `static`. Which serves the directory on port 8080.

I can see that -H is the option to format but I'm not sure how to pass in the options. Here is what I'm trying:

```
static -H "{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}"
```

Also:

```
static -H {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}
```

Which returns `undefined:1`

What is the proper way to pass the header option?

Comment: I have had trouble with this as well. Ended up putting my additional header information in a json file and called static with `static -f path/to/your/header-file.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [node-static README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-static#example-usage) it shows the `-H` option taking a JSON value:

> ```sh
> # specify additional headers (this one is useful for development) 
> $ static -H '{"Cache-Control": "no-cache, must-revalidate"}'
> serving "." at http://127.0.0.1:8080
> ```

...and we can see in the source that [it uses `JSON.parse`](https://github.com/cloudhead/node-static/blob/9fabe339698e88594ac81ddc2cb0a7065ad98113/bin/cli.js#L89-L91).

Neither of your attempts is valid JSON. In JSON, property names and strings must be surrounded by double quotes:

```sh
$ static -H '{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}'
```